# How do I add pagination to the link that I want to scrape?

Tags: pagination, screen-scraping

I'm using webscraper.io, and I want to scrape specific pages on this website https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?companies=co0144901&ref_=adv_prv

Problem is that I can't use the [1-20] method explained in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x8bZmUrJBl0

So basically my question, how is my link supposed to be structured if I wanted to make the [1-20] method work?

Used [1-20] method as explained in the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x8bZmUrJBl0

Comment: Well in fact it still works.. The difference is that IMDB doesn't save the page in the URL but the starting record. This means you could scrape it like that but you would have a lot of duplicates. I would advise you to work with a click on the next button :)